# Yodlee executeUserSearchRequest

Tags: yodlee

Am using the yodlee integration in my site. I have used the "executeUserSearchRequest" api call to perform search action based on the user details.

i have analyzed the documentation of yodlee in the below link for the param properties. 
Am not clear in the option of using user input.
transactionSearchRequest.userInput in the [documentation](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest).

What are the possible values i can pass through the transactionSearchRequest.userInput to restrict the search action. I have given the bank names in the user input but there is no changes in the retrived result.

NOTE: i have made the option of
"transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput"=>'false' to perform the search based on the given user input value.

Any help would be welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `transactionSearchRequest.userInput` parameter is a text filter. This can be used to identify transactions based on its description. You can pass any sequence of characters such as "ATM or Wallmart, etc" to get transaction having those specific description in it. If there is no matching transaction description with the given input string then the result will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteUserSearchRequest API is for getting transactions for a particular user, which are present in Yodlee system. You can provide different filters based on the requirement for fetching the transactions. For e.g. You can pass Date Range to get transactions for that particular duration, while you can also pass itemAccountID(this identifies each account individually) to get the transactions for that duration and belongs to that particular account. While this itemAccountID field is non-mandatory, so if you won't pass it on then it will look for transactions present for all the accounts for the defined date range.

If you are using userInput filter then it will look for the transactions where the provided keyword/string matches in Transaction Description or in User specified Transaction's "Memo" field.

[Here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Knowledge_Base/Transactions) is the link which could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

After referencing few more api calls in yodlee documentation and experimenting the search option in "executeUserSearchRequest" api i understand its only possible to search the description details using the transactionSearchRequest.userInput.

I managed to get the itemAccountId for each account using "Account/Summary/All" api call under the Core Services. [Yodlee Documentation](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/)

After passing the itemAccountId in `transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.itemAccountId.identifier` param of "executeUserSearchRequest" api, i managed to get the transaction of specific account.

Hope this might help someone.

Comment: The later part of the answer seems redundant in the context of question asked.